# Storing integer value in a variable gives different value

Tags: r, type-conversion, variable-assignment

I have a variable of integer type and it has value 1/1

```
> typeof(res[3,"V2.review/helpfulness"])
[1] "integer"
> res[3,"V2.review/helpfulness"]
[1]  1/1
```

Now when I store or convert it in integer I want value as the division of 1 and 1 that is 1
For example if I had 2/3 I want the value as 0.6666
But it gives me the result as

```
> as.integer(res[3,"V2.review/helpfulness"])
[1] 6
> as.double(res[3,"V2.review/helpfulness"])
[1] 6
```

Can somebody suggest a solution to this?

Comment: Can you show some of your data? You can copy-paste the output of `dput(head(res))` to your question.

Comment: It is a very big data

Comment: @Heroka Can you be specific what exactly do you want to know

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you are looking at a factor, not an integer:

```
DF = data.frame(x = c("1/1","2/3"))
typeof(DF$x) # "integer"
class(DF$x)  # "factor"
```

Knowing the storage type (with `typeof`) is rarely important. I suggest reading through the first couple sections of the R language definition to get up to speed on R's classes and other quirks that distinguish it from languages you may have used before. To get there, type `help.start()` and click "R Language Definition".

---

Reading from a file, R converts strings to factors, which are for categorical variables. It does not evaluate the arithmetic expression you have there (`1/1` or `2/3`), nor does it have any class for fractions, only integers, complex numbers and floats.

If you want to store your fraction precisely, store the numerator and denominator separately:

```
library(data.table)
DF[,c("num","den")] <- tstrsplit(as.character(DF$x), "/", type.convert = TRUE)

DF
#     x num den
# 1 1/1   1   1
# 2 2/3   2   3
```

To now evaluate the fraction, you can use

```
DF$xnum <- DF$num/DF$den # obviously not an integer

DF
#     x num den      xnum
# 1 1/1   1   1 1.0000000
# 2 2/3   2   3 0.6666667
```

To view the classes of all the columns, use

```
sapply(DF, class)
#         x       num       den      xnum 
#  "factor" "integer" "integer" "numeric"
```

The shortcut to evaluating the fraction is `DF$xnum <- sapply(as.character(DF$x), function(z) eval(parse(text=z)))`, but this hack is usually strongly discouraged.